# Select statement sqlite between dates

Tags: jquery, sqlite, date-format

I have one table storing two dates in the form: 2014-12-05 for example.  Those dates are date from and date to.  I want to select items from a *different* table which also has a date column.  So I want to do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
```

except the fromdate and todate columns are from table1, whereas 'date' is from table2.  Is there a succinct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do some kind of join between the the two tables and select entries from the join. A simple cartesian join can be achieved by comma-separating the tables you are querying from.

```
create table holidays (
        name text not null,
        fromdate text not null,
        todate text not null
);

create table appointments (
        name text not null,
        date text not null
);

insert into holidays values ('Christmas Holiday', '2014-12-05', '2014-12-24');

insert into appointments values ('Dentist', '2014-11-06');
insert into appointments values ('Doctor', '2014-12-06');

select h.name, a.name, a.date
        from appointments a, holidays h
        where a.date between h.fromdate and h.todate;
```

Comment: Brilliant, out of all the code explanations I've seen, this really is the clearest one.  It works thanks a lot!